# Print Each Individual Element in Array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I'm pretty new to Python and could use a hand in telling the computer what I want. I understand that

```
A = np.array([[3,5,50],[30,2,6],[25,1,1]]

for i in A:
    print(i)
```

gives the output:

```
[3,5,50]
[30,2,6]
[25,1,1]
```

And, I understand that

```
for i,j,k in A:
    print(i,j,k)
```

gives

```
3 5 50 
30 2 6 
25 1 1
```

But, how would you write a loop to get the following output without using a print statement three times?

```
3
5
50
30
20
6
25
1
1
```

(this is really general and I'm applying it to a large array and wanting to set specific values in the array equal to zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using multiple arguments in print it uses the default separator which is a white space. You can specify it to be a new line:

```
for i,j,k in A:
    print(i,j,k, sep="\n")
```

One way of doing so is using [`np.ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) or [`np.flatten()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
for i in A.ravel():
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

```
for i in A:
  for j in i:
    print(j)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
for i in range(len(A)):
  for j in range(len(A[i])):
    print(A[i][j])
```

Comment: The A.ravel() sold me for the best answer to this question, but I want to try and implement this method in my code. Could you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751580/masking-using-pixel-statistics